# RenderTransform binding inside Style in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, binding, wpf-style

I have the following code. Why is the `Text`-Binding working and the `TranslateTransform.X` not?

```
<Window xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        x:Class="WpfApplication2.MainWindow"
        Title="MainWindow">

    <Window.Resources>
        <Style TargetType="TextBlock" x:Key="txtStyle">
            <Setter Property="HorizontalAlignment" Value="Left"/>

            <Setter Property="Text" Value="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}, Path=Width, Mode=OneWay}"/>

            <Setter Property="RenderTransform">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <TranslateTransform X="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}, Path=Width, Mode=OneWay}"/>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </Style>
    </Window.Resources>

    <StackPanel>
        <TextBlock Canvas.Top="50" Background="Lime" Width="200" Style="{StaticResource txtStyle}"/>
        <TextBlock Canvas.Top="100" Background="LightBlue" Width="300" Style="{StaticResource txtStyle}"/>
    </StackPanel>
</Window>
```

Answer (score 2):

You need a `FindAncestor` Binding.

```
<TranslateTransform X="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType=TextBlock}, Path=Width, Mode=OneWay}"/>
```

Comment: Thanks, the binding works, but I get the following error in the Output Window:

System.Windows.Data Error: 4 : Cannot find source for binding with reference 'RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType='System.Windows.Controls.TextBlock', AncestorLevel='1''. BindingExpression:Path=Width; DataItem=null; target element is 'TranslateTransform' (HashCode=10756226); target property is 'X' (type 'Double')